# Can I put DXA error views in a module area?

Tags: dxa, dxa-net

DXA can use a couple of views to render error messages: [`ServerError.cshtml`, `SectionError.cshtml`](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/tree/release/1.7/Site/Views/Shared) and [`EntityError.cshtml`](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/blob/release/1.7/webapp-net/Core/Areas/Core/Views/Entity/EntityError.cshtml).

Out of the box, the `EntityError.cshtml` comes from the Core area, the other modules are in the `Views\Shared` of the web application. You can also put all those views in `Views\Shared`.

However, when I moved those views in my custom module's area the webapp could not find the views. It would only search for views in the the `Areas/Core/Views` and `Views/Shared`. Can I tell DXA or .NET MVC to search in my area as well?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that `EntityError.cshtml` is not in `Views\Shared` OOTB can be considered a defect (quirk at least). Can you create an issue (and possibly also a Pull Request) on GitHub for that?

Regarding putting those Views in your own Module/Area: what would be the reason to do that? What if you use multiple Modules which have those Views defined?

Note that DXA 1.7 allows you to configure a "Default Module" which makes it possible to pick up Views from another Module than `Core` by default. However, I don't think this covers those error Views.

Comment: In the mean time I created an issue for the `EntityError`.https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/issues/39 :)

Comment: So the short answer is, it is not possible :)  Since the `EntityError` is in the core module I tried to bring it into my own module so I can remove the core module area). I think it is fine putting it in the `Views/Shared` since it is not using the area registration anyway. A good reason to keep it in the module would be so that all views are nicely in one place.